# App is stuck on splash screen when opening it in Testflight

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-ios, testflight

I am trying to run the app through(testflight). Upload went well but when I downloaded app on Testflight and opened it, it seems to be stuck on splash screen(waiting for more then an hour but no luck).

App seems to work on expo.io when I published app over there and scanned/opened it with expo app.

Attaching my app.js and app.json below.

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "APPNAME",
    "slug": "APPNAME",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "33.0.0",
    "platforms": ["ios", "android", "web"],
    "version": "1.0.3",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/images/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.APPNAME.iosapp"
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.APPNAME.android"
    }
  }
}
```

App.js

```
import { AppLoading } from "expo"
import { Asset } from "expo-asset"
import * as Font from "expo-font"
import React from "react"
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons"
import { Provider } from "react-redux"
import store from "./store"
import Root from "./Root.js"
import { YellowBox } from "react-native"
import AppNavigator from "./navigation/AppNavigator"

YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(["Remote debugger"])

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { isReady: false }
  }

  async loadResourcesAsync() {
    await Promise.all([
      Asset.loadAsync([
        require("./assets/images/robot-dev.png"),
        require("./assets/images/robot-prod.png")
      ]),
      Font.loadAsync({
        // This is the font that we are using for our tab bar
        ...Ionicons.font,
        "Rubik-medium": require("./assets/fonts/Rubik-Medium.ttf"),
        "Rubik-regular": require("./assets/fonts/Rubik-Regular.ttf"),
        "Rubik-light": require("./assets/fonts/Rubik-Light.ttf"),
        geo: require("./assets/fonts/geogrotesque.ttf")
      })
    ])
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.isReady) {
      return (
        <AppLoading
          startAsync={this.loadResourcesAsync}
          onError={error => console.warn(error)}
          onFinish={() => this.setState({ isReady: true })}
        />
      )
    }

    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AppNavigator />
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading SDK version to 29.0.0 will solve your problem. But it's just a temporary fix. I hope this issue will be solved in the upcoming SDK releases.